# $2D$ diagrams of 3+$1D$ Minkowski spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

In the Minkowski diagrams, if we take $y=0$ and $z=0$, and just plot $x$ horizontally, and $ct$ vertically, what does a a point on the $x$-axis represent?

Comment: What do you think it means for $t=0$? What are you struggling with here?

Comment: What does it mean on a PHY 101 position vs time graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point over the $x$ axis, let's say $x_0$, will represent an event happening in the instant $t=0$ in the point with spatial coordinates $(x=x_0,y=0,z=0)$. Imagine that you are and observer in the origin of the coordinate system. The x-axis of the Minkowski diagram of your coordinate system will represent  all the simultaneous events (with respect to you) that happened in the instant $t=0$ (as it was marked by your wrist watch) in spatial locations with different x-coordinate.